# Why does container work in Docker but no in GKE

Tags: containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Containerfile installing a go binary<sup>[1]</sup>.

When I build & execute the container via `docker run` on my Desktop it works fine.
When I however deploy the same container on a GKE pod I get an error:
`/bin/sh: /root/service: not found`

I would assume that this is a type of security lockdown - but not sure how to get it working on GKE.

[1]:

```
FROM golang:1.19-alpine AS build

RUN go install github.com/QubitProducts/exporter_exporter@v0.4.5


FROM alpine

COPY --from=build --chown=root:root /go/bin/exporter_exporter /root/service

CMD /root/service
```

Comment: for me the error is `exec /bin/sh: exec format error`  not found is could be due to missing binary or file, exec format error due to I was building on Mac m1 ARM and running it on AMD process of GKE node so hope it's not same for you. For me docker running locally but due to processor platform change getting error. do check once `not found` could be due to half created build or file missing at CMD command last line.

Comment: Where did you build the container?  Looks like you might have built for a different architecture as Harsh says above.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the volume permission issues for your container. When you are running your container in docker the docker daemon will have  access to the root and running your container won’t throw any error since the daemon is already having root access. In kubernetes, pods and containers won’t be having root access by default so when building an image for kubernetes you need to mention the required config maps for mounting root volumes and for executing your code on root volumes.

Comment: @abergmeier can you revert back whether your issue has been resolved..